# How can I re active my question?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

My question had been put on hold: closed as too broad by ...

[what-is-the-best-way-to-coach-a-junior-in-software-development](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41074/what-is-the-best-way-to-coach-a-junior-in-software-development)

I've edited the question and then add a comment for the people who closed the question to help me re activate the question.

No reaction so far.

Can somebody explain me what I should do please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I edited your post to focus on the problem you're facing.  In its current form, it's asking a very open-ended question.

In this case I'd recommend adding more details to narrow down the problem.  Perhaps you can describe in a paragraph or two why you felt unprepared in the first coaching session.  Tell us what worked and what didn't work. At the end, just make sure you're asking a specific question and avoid being too open ended.  Let us know if you need any more editing help.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. 
1- Why is it not allowed to have an open ended question? The answers (I believe) could well be pointers or thought to go on the right direction.
2- I've edited my question again, and waited.... Why is it still closed?