# Quick to close, slow to re-open

Tags: discussion

I'm very new at SE and I've asked few questions so far.
I'm a bit frustrated by the lack of reactivity to re open my question.

**Story so far:**
It had been put on hold very quickly (that's ok for me so far) but then, I've tried to comply to the quality standard but I'm still waiting for feedback or to have my question re activated!

[my question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41074/what-is-the-best-way-to-prepare-to-coach-a-junior-in-software-development)

[My demand of feedback](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/how-can-i-re-active-my-question)

*That's for the particular issue that brings me here.*

**Now the wider problem:**

All new questions are shiny and get all the attention. Since I asked my question 22 days ago, I suppose nobody care for re opening it. Same thing for my demand of feeback; there is no follow up.

The ratio *time to close* **/** *time to reopen* is too low.

**What should be done?**

*NB: I don't think it's duplicate of [High volume of questions being put On Hold or Closed - is that a problem?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/high-volume-of-questions-being-put-on-hold-or-closed-is-that-a-problem) as I'm ok with my question being on hold, I just want to find a way to reopen question*

Comment: as far as I can see, [reviewers weren't convinced](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/26609) about reopening

Comment: I regret the lack of communication. I'm all for refining the question to make it better. In this case it appears I'm working on it and asking for advice that does not come. Maybe I should re-work the question and re-reate a question?

Comment: Read the Help Center on how to ask.  Ask a question that states the specific goal you want to achieve.  If you can imagine a book on the subject then you are asking for something with too large of a scope.    Also realize that this question teeters on the what skills do I learn, which is off topic.  In this case since you were directed by your boss to do this, the best first step is to talk with him about his expectations from you in this task.  Then go about meeting those expectations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One question does not a syndrome make.

This site receives *a lot* of off-topic questions, generally in the category of 'too broad' and 'asking for advice'. If all goes well, these questions will be closed, and never reopened. So, to make your case, you'd need to add links to at least a handful of questions that were.

1. closed
2. actually improved to be appropriate
3. languished

There is a review queue for high-rep users that highlights questions that have the potential for a reopen, they don't just languish on the front page.

Comment: Fair enough, after looking for similar cases I could only find one easily (1 year old and still closed). Having not the time for a deeper search (and seeing a lot of the questions on meta refers to deleted question) I cannot make my case. 
:(

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the question just isn't the right type for the site. I read your question when it was first asked, when you asked why, and now again.

The problem I see is that you tried to train somebody before and you weren't happy with the experience. The only answer I can give you is: take what you learned last time, think about options to try, and try them. After you have been a mentor several times you will get better at it, or you won't.

You are expecting a long answer you even lay out the three parts:

> The answer I would have expected would have been something like that:
>   There should be 3 axis of improvement for a Junior. 1 - The Technical
>   part 2 - The understanding of the (software) shipping flow 3 - Work
>   behaviour
>
> As for the first one, the Junior will be asked to follow the project
>   at hand with precise set of goals to achieve linked with some bonus
>   goals. (Ex. in software engineering, we are making web services so we
>   are expecting basic understanding of the messages flow, actual use of
>   the architecture, etc. Bonus goals would be: challenge of the
>   architecture, recognition of room for improvement part of the code,
>   and implementation of new architecture for a 'in scoped' project)
>
> As for the development in the team, the understanding of the shipping
>   flow is very important (more over if the Junior does not see himself
>   as a long term developer). The understanding of the business, tests,
>   deployment, etc. All of these things have to be integrated full in the
>   first 4 months. Bonus point for pointing out problem in the flow and
>   ways to improve.
>
> Finally, the work ethic. For a Junior to enter a new company will
>   define his behaviour for the rest of his carrer. It's important to
>   spot short coming in communication (verbal, writing etc.) and
>   encourage certain kind of behaviour (sending a mail to re confirm an
>   oral decision for instance). It's also interesting to develop his
>   curiosity toward all of those soft skills as it would greatly help him
>   later.

Unfortunately for me your question as constructed makes it even harder to answer. You have no specifics in the question but want a long answer.

The best advice may be to ask the company for help; ask your boss for guidance (the boss can mentor you), or find a book.

Comment: The specificity of the case was not held here as the issue. It was showing an example of a situation.
The issue here is: Should something being done to improve the 'quick to close/late to reopen' syndrome.

Comment: If the question isn't appropriate the time to reopen will be infinite.